# Find All Parents based on certain record

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need some helps about SQL code. I have 2 tables, the first one is table name

```
NameID   Name      
1          John          
2          Paul          
3          Jessica          
4          Nancy          
5          Sam          
6          Jane
7          Jimmy
```

The second one is table Family

```
 FamilyID   NameID    ChildID
    1          1           2
    2          1           3
    3          2           4
    4          3           5
    5          3           6
    6          5           7
```

Field "NameID" and "ChildID" in table Family are connected to field "NameID" in table Name. So if I put it in a tree it will be like this

```
         John
         /  \
      Paul  Jessica
      /       /  \
   Nancy    Sam  Jane
            /
          Jimmy
```

What I need is SQL code that can find "All" Parents for certain record. For example :

1. I want to know all parents from Jane, the results will be : Jessica,
   John
2. I want to know all parents from Jimmy, the results will be : Sam,
   Jessica, John
3. I want to know all parents from Nancy, the results will be : Paul, John

Comment: Could you please include the query that you tried?

Comment: Actually I am still working on it using cte recursive but not finished yet

Comment: Do you mean all ancestors? That's what worked example #2 suggests. A CTE is what I'd do.

Comment: @PeterWone yep you could say "all ancestors" sorry if you get confused by my words. I am new at using CTE so I need some helps here :) .

Comment: Which database server are you using? Oracle?

Comment: @JohnSaunders Mirosoft SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: The real world family tree is complicated than your example. Imagine Jimmy's parent are Sam and Jane, Nancy and Jessica is parent of Sam. Then Jimmy has all nodes as his parents..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go, Use a recursive CTE as follows:

```
  DECLARE @pName VARCHAR(20)
  SET @pName = 'Jane'

  ;WITH  RecursiveFamilyCTE
          AS (
               SELECT
                ParentName.NAME,
                ParentName.NameID,
                f.ChildID
               FROM
                dbo.Family AS f
                JOIN NAME AS ChildName
                  ON f.ChildID = ChildName.NameID
                JOIN Name AS ParentName
                  ON f.NameID = ParentName.NameID
               WHERE
                 ChildName.NAME = @pName

               UNION ALL

               SELECT 
                ParentName.NAME,
                ParentName.NameID,
                f.ChildID
               FROM
                dbo.Family AS f
                JOIN NAME AS ChildName
                  ON f.ChildID = ChildName.NameID
                JOIN Name AS ParentName
                  ON f.NameID = ParentName.NameID
                JOIN RecursiveFamilyCTE
                  ON f.ChildID = RecursiveFamilyCTE.NameID
             )
    SELECT
      NAME
    FROM
      RecursiveFamilyCTE
```

Comment: I changed it just now to use the @pName parameter which was being ignored in my first post.

Answer (score 0):

Recursive query is the way to go on this one. This, below, is a flexible query that you can run without parameters.

```
with familytree as (
  select childid, nameid 
  from family
  where nameid is not null

  union all

  select f.childid, t.nameid  
  from familytree t 
  inner join family f on t.childid = f.nameid
),
treedetails as (
  select
    p.nameid as parentid, p.name as parent, 
    c.nameid as childid, c.name as child
  from familytree a
  left join name p on a.nameid = p.nameid
  left join name c on a.childid = c.nameid
)
-- uncomment the query of your choice
-- select * from treedetails where child = 'Jimmy'
-- select * from treedetails where child = 'Jane' 
-- select * from treedetails where child = 'Nancy'
-- 
-- show me children and grandchildren of Jessica
-- select * from treedetails where parent = 'Jessica'
```

Sample: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f7030/4